# creating a class of functions with pandas

Tags: python, class, oop, object, pandas

im going to make a program to do some functions that I will regularly use and thought I would make some classes for it (my first time making classes)
I need some help

I need a class that reads a dataframe and then prints the tail of the dataframe to start, then I will write functions for this class that will output a regression and fourier transform on it but already having trouble printing the tail... here is my code:

```
class my_data:
def __init__(self, the_data):
    self.the_data = pd.DataFrame(the_data)

def print_tail(self, the_data):
    return pd.tail(the_data)

a = my_data(the_data = pd.read_csv('training_x.csv'))

print(a.print_tail())
```

I thought by creating the class and passing pd.DataFrame through it, it inherits the functions of pandas if I wrap it in my own function within the class?
thanks for the help guys im a bit lost

Comment: You might be better off starting with a basic tutorial on classes, what they're for, how Python implements them and building simple ones from scratch. You're jumping into the deep end here and it's only going to cause you headaches...

Comment: actually just sorted it, method within the class does not need the_data to be redefined right? already has the variable the_data as a pd dataframe so def print_tail() just needs to pass self  and return the_data.tail()? I sorted it that way, thanks anyway man, and yeah I know what you mean about a basic tutorial, but i just cant be bothered trying to simulate a customer or a bank account with classes